# How to access Truffle deployed contracts with app's javascript code?

Tags: truffle, truffle-contract, truffle-deployment

I have some smart contracts deployed with Truffle on the local Ganache network, but I don't know how to access it with the app's javascript in order to make function calls to the contract. How would I be able to access it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use either the deployed() method or the at() method. Here's some [relevant documentation from Truffle](http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/contracts).

Answer (score 0):

Check [this tutorial](https://link.medium.com/nPFxrxIOFS) on how to manage and interact with contracts deployed using truffle